# How can I get it to login with more than 2 tokens?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I get it to login with more than 2 tokens?   help me pls

```
error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

my code

```
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN") & os.getenv("TOKEN2") & os.getenv("TOKEN3"), bot=False)
```

Comment: `&` is the bitwise AND operator. Why are you trying to use that with token strings?

Comment: Use `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: I don't want to merge. I want to login with 2 or more tokens

Comment: I don't know Discord, what does it mean to "login with N tokens"?

Comment: `client.run()` isn't used to login, you login with `client.login()`. As far as I can tell from the documentation, it only takes one token argument.

Comment: Do you want to try multiple tokens until it's successful? Then you need a loop.